# Async/await errors being swallowed in bound function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, async-await

I am running an Express application that uses async/await.

I have two routes that looks like this:

```
app.post('/add-item', item.bind(null, 'add'))
app.post('/remove-item', item.bind(null, 'remove'))
```

The route handler is defined as follows:

```
async function item (action, req, res, next) {
  if (action === 'add') {
    var result = await addItemFromDB()
    res.json(result)
  } else {
    var result = await removeItemFromDB()
    res.json(result)
  }
}
```

Because I want to avoid wrapping the `addItemFromDB` and `removeItemFromDB` functions in `try/catch` I wrap it in the helper function `asyncRequest`:

```
asyncRequest(async function item(req, res, next) {
  if (action === 'add') {
    var result = await addItemFromDB()
    res.json(result)
  } else {
    var result = await removeItemFromDB()
    res.json(result)
  }
})
```

With `asyncRequest` being defined as:

```
function asyncRequest (handler) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    return handler(req, res, next).catch(next)
  }
}
```

However, all errors that occur in `addItemFromDB` and `removeItemFromDB` are silently swallowed. What I have discovered is, that when I remove the `.bind(null, 'add')` etc. everything works as expected.

Any ideas to why this is the case?

Comment: I was, thx for the correction!

Comment: You cannot call `asyncRequest` on a function declaration, and you have omitted your `action` parameter. What are you really doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use

```
app.post('/add-item', asyncRequest(item.bind(null, 'add')));
app.post('/remove-item', asyncRequest(item.bind(null, 'remove)));
```

Probably you tried to call `asyncRequest` on your custom `item` function that takes 4 parameters, which is not what the `asyncRequest` function expects of its `handler` argument.

Comment: Yeah, it must be the number of parameters that I forgot to consider. Thanks!